# subtracting two numbers to equal 1?

Tags: math

I was wondering if there's a sort of algorithm where if you subtract two numbers it adds to 1. However, the number you subtract the two numbers from has to be equal.

so basically:
(a - c) + (b - c) = 1

Comment: This isn't very clear. What are you trying to find? All such values of a, b, and c that can be any integer at all? Or something else? You need to be clear about what you are trying to solve and the domains that apply to the variables.

Comment: Take any `a` and `b`, and there is a `c=(a+b-1)/2` which makes the above true.

Comment: @ja72 how did you do that?

Comment: I solved the equation `(a-c) + (b-c) = 1` for `c`. Simple algebra,

Comment: The question I have is, what is the significance of this particular relationship?

Comment: `def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    a = x1 - x2
    if a == 0:
        y = 2
    else:
        y = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    if y <= 1 and y >= -1:
        x = 1
        if x2 < x1:
            y *= -1
            x *= -1
    else:
        y = 1
        x = (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1)
        if y2 < y1:
            y *= -1
            x *= -1
    return x, y`

Comment: @ja72 I made an algorithm that found 360 degree slope. As in the slope cannot be "infinity".

Comment: Normally a line on the plane is defined with the coefficients `a`, `b`, `c` used in the equation `a*x+b*y+c=0`. The "slope" is defined by the direction vector `(-b,a)`. For example, the line `x=3` with infinite slope has an equation `1*x+0*y-3=0` and direction vector `(0,1)` pointing upwards.

Comment: I KNEW I WAS OVER COMPLICATING IT. Thanks for showing me the light @ja72

Comment: @RandomGuy - definitely. When I saw your "solution", I had so say something to steer you in the right direction as it was obviously a poor attempt to re-invent the wheel. See if you can find an [online reference for planar lines](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~king/coursedir/m445w04/notes/vector/equations.html) or [something more mathy](http://www.ipb.uni-bonn.de/book-pcv/pdfs/PCV-A-sample-page.pdf) going deeper into homogeneous coordinate (the 'abc' coefficients of a line).

Comment: @RandomGuy - hey it turns out I have posted something on Mathematics.SE about the `(a,b,c)` coordinates of a line. I recommend you [take a look](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/727847/3301). Also, feel free to post any questions about math in [Mathematics.SE] and not [SO].

Comment: Oh, thank you. I will make sure to take a look c: @ja72

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a little off-topic, but just using math :

```
(a - c) + (b - c) = 1 
a - c + b - c = 1 
a + b - 2c = 1 
a = 1 + 2c - b
```

So just generate randomly `b` and `c` and than plug that values into `1 + 2c - b` and that's the value to assign to `a` in order to have `(a - c) + (b - c) = 1`

Comment: Math. Such a powerful algorithm. It should be taught in schools, for real.

Comment: @Amadan damn right